# fade in and move down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an animation set on my homepage headline using CSS to make it fade in when the page loads.

I have seen on other sites a really impressive animation that will fade in the title and move it down slightly.

How would I have to alter my code to be able to achieve this?

```
<div class="homepage">
    <div class="headline">
        <h1><span>WELCOME</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="subheadline">
        <h1>
            <span>To the home of</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="subheadline">
        <h1>
            <span>Multimedia Journalist</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="subheadline">
        <h1>
            <span>Dan Morris</span>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll" id="contactlink">Let's talk</a>
    <div class="down-link">
        <a class="w-downlink" href="#about">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.headline {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 78px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-right: auto;
    font: 200 18px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #676767;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in .5s both;
    animation: fadeIn .1s ease-in .5s both;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide this in a code snippet or fiddle -- much easier for others to identify what your specific need and challenge is. Also, this is very close to a *can you troubleshoot my code for me* type question. If you provide the specific details of what it is that's not working for you, it will be much better received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `top` property along with `position: relative;`:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/sc7dduue/

```css
.headline {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 78px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-right: auto;
    font: 200 18px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #676767;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        top: -40px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        top: -40px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0px;
    }
}


.fadeIn {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in .5s both;
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in .5s both;
}
```

```html
 <div class="homepage">
<div class="headline fadeIn">
<h1><span>WELCOME</span></h1>
</div>
<div class="subheadline">
  <h1><span>To the home of</span></h1></div><div class="subheadline"><h1><span>Multimedia Journalist</span></h1></div>
<div class="subheadline"><h1><span>Dan Morris</span></h1></div>
<a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll" id="contactlink">Let's talk</a>
<div class="down-link"><a class="w-downlink" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's brilliant. How would i go about make the headline move down and the subheadline move up?

Comment: Set its position to `relative` as well. At 0% of the animation, use `top: 40px;` and at 100% use `top: 0px;` (or which ever value you think looks best). Or you could also use `bottom: -40px` at 0% and `bottom: 0px` at 100%. That's how `position: relative` works: it positions an object, based on the given position, relative to its origin. So when we say "40px from the top", it moves 40px from the top. Moving it negative 40px from the bottom will move it down too. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/sc7dduue/2/

Comment: Also: In that fiddle I unscrambled the mess you had going with the subline. you MUSTN'T use several `<h1>` in one page, nor was there any reason to: Just set breaks `<br />`

Comment: @benphillps Any reason why the animation would be slow and jumpy?

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't be the case... Really slow browser / device?

Comment: This lets the browser perform the animation to the best of its abilities.
Would you accept this answer?